# Async request with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

```
$.ajax({
        async:false,
        url: "ajax/stop_billed_reservation_delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType : "json",
        data : { "rid" : <?php echo $_GET['reservationId']; ?> },
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
            return result;
        }
    });
```

my target is return ajax response. but before the return response script run other parts. How can i fix this issue !

ajax response should be **true** or **false**
so return value should be **true** or **false**

This script is used for stop to form submission.
if return value is true, form should submit, otherwise (false) for should be not submit.

( This code is used to validate form )

Comment: You get `rid` value in `stop_billed_reservation_delete.php` file?

Comment: no point in returning a value in the asynchronously called success function

Comment: `ajax response should be true or false so return value should be true or false` yes, the success callback returns true or false (see my previous comment to realise the futility of this return value) ... but `$.ajax` returns some jQuery object immediately, not when the result is known

Comment: `This script is used for stop to form submission. if return value is true, form should submit, otherwise (false) for should be not submit.` ultimately, you can't prevent a form from submitting by using an asynchronous function - preventDefault can not be called at some arbitrary later time - you'll need to rethink your code (always prevent the form submitting, and if the result of this ajax is true, perform the form submission yourself ... using $.ajax

Comment: @VinayKaklotar yes

Comment: @JaromandaX , Form is not using ajax to submit data. it's just validation part

Comment: I know ... but it will need to -... just like in the answer you accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ajax by default is asynchronous hence why it is not waiting for the ajax response. `async: false` would not work because it is already deprecated. You can run the form submission in the success function of the ajax function.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "ajax/stop_billed_reservation_delete.php",
    type: "POST",
    dataType : "json",
    data : { "rid" : <?php echo $_GET['reservationId']; ?> },
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
        if(result){
            submitForm(); //Run the function that will submit the form.
        }
    }
});

function submitForm(){
    //Relevant code for submitting the form.
    . . . . . .
}
```